# Running .env files within a docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have been struggling to add env variables into my container for the past 3 hrs :( I have looked through the [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) docs but haven't managed to get it to work.

I have built my image using `docker build -t sellers_json_analysis .` which works fine.

I then go to run it with: `docker run -d --env-file ./env sellers_json_analysis`

As per the docs: `$ docker run --env-file ./env.list ubuntu bash` but I get the following error:

```
docker: open ./env: no such file or directory.
```

The `.env` file is in my root directory

But when running `docker run --help` I am unable to find anything about env variables, but it doesn't provide the following:

`Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

So not sure I am placing things incorrectly. I could add my variables into the dockerfile but I want to keep it as a public repo as it's a project I would like to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is wrong path, either use `.env` or `./.env`, when you use `./env` it mean a file named `env` in current directory

```sh
docker run -d --env-file .env sellers_json_analysis
```